# plistにデータが反映されない

Tags: swift3

いつもお世話になっております。

swiftにてplistへのデータの書き込みが上手くできず四苦八苦しております。
writeされたら、直ちにplistに反映される認識でおりますが、plistを参照しても初期値のままでした。
ご教授ご鞭撻のほどよろしくお願い致します。

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class SaveData {

    let filepath: String? = {
        return Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SaveData", ofType: "plist")
    }()

    init() {
    }

    func updateHome(id: Int) -> Bool {

        if
            let path = self.filepath,
            let data = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        {
            data.setValue(1, forKey: "home")
            return data.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)  // trueとなりますがplistが更新されていない
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

以上よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Bundle内のリソースは書き込み禁止です。アプリの初回起動時にドキュメントディレクトリなど、アプリが書き込み権限を持つパスにファイルをコピーして、以降はそちらのファイルを読み書きする、といったことが必要になります。ちなみに`write(toFile:atomically:)`がその状況で`true`を返すのであれば[バグ報告](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/)を送っても良い不具合ですね。

Comment: いつもご回答頂きありがとうございます！Bundleは書き込み禁止な領域だったのですね。大変勉強になりました。テンプレートファイルのように扱いローカルへコピーし書き込み利用したいと思います。バグ報告を申請してみました。ありがとうございます。